# Added subtitles to video however audio is removed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, calayer, catextlayer

I have followed the instructions in the link below for adding subtitles (under the section 'Just Like Those Foreign Films — Adding Subtitles to Videos'):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos#comments

However, for some reason, the sound is removed when I play the video created.

What should I do to maintain that audio in the final video too?

ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the comment of `November 22, 2013, 4:05 AM` and the two following ones (currently in page 2).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm sorry can you please give me further details,  I am still quite new to objective-c and am having difficulty putting this together. Thanks again for your help.